# How to introduce a shell command to create a file into makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I'm having trouble with my makefile:

Need to create a program X from A.o and B.o. However, I don't have the files in the directory to create A.o. yet. I first need to run a command on one of the files in the directory to produce the required files for A.o and it has to be within the makefile. What's the best way to do that?

I tried adding it as $(command) under the rules for A.o:

```
    TARGET=programX
    OBJS=A.o B.o
    all: $(TARGET)
    $(TARGET): $(OBJS) 
    $(LINK) $(FLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

A.o: files
    $(command)
    $(LINK) $(FLAGS) file

B.o: files
    $(LINK) $(FLAGS) file
```

It keeps spitting an  error that no rule was given to create target that's required for A.o. If I move it up, it says that commands commence before first target.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting here but wasn't sure what was going on exactly and didn't want to mess file contents up. Can you please correct the formatting? Paste your makefile contents then select the lines and use the `{}` tool to format them as a block of code.

Comment: I fixed the formatting

Comment: What is `command`? It isn't a make variable (like `TARGET` or `LINK` etc.). You want to remove the leading spaces from the first three lines in that snippet too (if they are actually spaces they likely don't matter but they aren't necessary there either).

Comment: With a makefile that is this "obfuscated" it is also very hard to know what problem make is having. Can you either give us the original or reproduce a minimal but working makefile that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your command into a rule for creating the files that it creates, so make knows when it's needed.

Also, your formatting was broken.  Targets need to not be indented, IIRC.

```
TARGET=programX
OBJS=A.o B.o

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJS) 
    $(LINK) $(FLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

# run command from its own rule, so it happens when needed
files:
    $(command)

A.o: files
    $(LINK) $(FLAGS) file

B.o: files
    $(LINK) $(FLAGS) file
```

Or, if you want your command to always run right before linking `A.o`, remove the dependency of `files` from the rule for `A.o`.  Then make can run that rule even when `files` don't / doesn't exist.

BTW, your example is *weird*.  Linking is normally a process the combines multiple `.o` object files into a single executable or shared library.  So the rule to *create* `A.o` shouldn't do any linking, just compiling.

Also, you can reduce duplication in your Makefile by using [automatic variables like $<](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) on the command line in your rule, instead of writing something as a dependency and on the command line.  This even lets you make pattern rules for everything that's compiled the same way.  This stuff gets more useful as your Makefile gets bigger.

IIRC, one of Make's built-in rules is something like:

```
%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

(Actually, the built-in rule won't have a dependency on $(HEADERS), just the `.c` of the same name as the required `.o`.  Putting this rule in your Makefile would tell make that all your object files need a rebuild if even one of the headers changed.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example makefile which assumes that your sources are under "src" directoy, the generated object files should be under "obj" directory and binary should reside in "bin" directory

```
#this is where teh source files should be
SRC_DIR=src

OBJ_DIR=obj
BIN_DIR=bin
EXECUTABLE=exe
EXE=$(BIN_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

#compile and link using g++
CC=g++
LD=g++

CPP_FILES=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)

OBJ_FILES=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(CPP_FILES))

#this is a virtual target which allows to create the directories 
#first and then create the executable
PHONY: default
default : create_directories $(EXE)

#main target
$(EXE) : $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(LD) -o $@ $^

#template rule for creating all prerequisite files (e.g. *.o files)
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^


PHONY: create_directories
create_directories:
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
```

It is easy to write a makefile if you think top down. Like what is the command producing your final target and what are the prerequisites? Once you figure this out it is easy to add rules for generating prerequistes.

Comment: It's a bit too advanced. I was wondering if there is a way to introduce a shell command to run a file which resides in the same directory to create other .c/.cpp files for one of the objects (A.o). right before it is created.